# Visual c++ for Linux Development debugging shared library

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, visual-studio-debugging

I would like to debug `shared library` in Visual C++ Linux Development. Debugging executable file works well, but the breakpoint does not hit for shared library. How can I fix up?

[Attached file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Akouzp76ufQ7aMBviqr4p1G7JCQ) is visual studio solution including .c and Makefile.

[image]
[image]

Example is very simple.

1. open shared library
2. read pointer of function in shared library
3. call the function.

Program works well. But Debugging shared library does not works. The breakpoint in main.c hits but the breakpoint in com.c does `NOT` hit.

```
/* main.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    void* dl_handle;
    dl_handle = dlopen("../so/libcom.so.1", RTLD_LAZY);

    if (!dl_handle) {
        printf(" error : %s \n", dlerror());
        return 0;
    }

    printf(" now call minicommon.h's function.. that is < void print_n(int n) >...\n");
    void(*pFunc)(int);
    pFunc = dlsym(dl_handle, "print_n");
    (*pFunc)(18);

    return 0;
}

/* com.c */

#include <stdio.h>

void print_n(int a)
{
    printf("SO - print: [%d]\n", a);
}

/* Makefile for main.c */

all: main

main: main.o
    gcc -W -Wall -gdwarf-2 -o main ../so/libcom.so.1 main.o -ldl

main.o: main.c
    gcc -Wall -c -gdwarf-2 -o main.o main.c

clean:
    rm -rf *.o main

/* Makefile for com.c */
all: libcom.so.1

libcom.so.1: com.o
    gcc -shared -gdwarf-2 -o libcom.so.1 com.o

com.o: com.c
    gcc -Wall -c -gdwarf-2 -o com.o com.c -fPIC

clean:
    rm -rf *.o libcom.so.1
```

Before shared library is opened, can I debug it?

Environment
 - Window 10
 - CentOS 7 in VirtualBox
 - Visual Studio 2015 update 3
 - Visual C++ for linux Development 1.0.7

Comment: Any error message while the breakpoint skipped? Actually even it's really limitation of VS2015, it won't be fixed, since VS2017 is the the latest tool ,MS will update it frequently,similar issue reported in VS2015: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/19453/break-point-in-c-code-of-java-c-android-app-not-hi.html  But in VS2017 the issue happened before has been fixed Since update 15.5.3: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/49137/-could-not-debug-into-arm-c-dynamic-shared-library.html So I'll suggest you try VS2017 with the newest update instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to debug any binary (which includes shared libraries) you need the debugging symbols being available, either compiled into the binary itself, or as a separate file.

In most Linux distributions you can install the debugging symbols as separate package; Ubuntu for instance names these packages `<packagename>-dbg`. Check if these are available in your development environment, too.

Comment: Thank you for your attention and advice. I don't know Linux System well. I could comprehend it with your assistance.

Comment: @blank_popup, If Murphy's suggestion is helpful for you, would you please mark it as the answer? So it could help other community members who get the same issue. Have a nice day:)